# Call Closure defined in other script

Tags: variables, binding, groovy

What is the correct and simplest way to access a closure defined within another script in Groovy.  This might not be the best design, but I have a closure defined in

SomeScript.groovy

```
bindingC = {
    ...
}

def localC = {
    ...
}
```

OtherScript.groovy

```
SomeScript s = new SomeScript()
s.bindingC(...);
s.localC(...);
```

Note: SomeScript.groovy is program logic and OtherScript.groovy is unit testing logic.  They are both in the same package and I'm able to access methods in SomeScript already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways (i'm aware) you can use to achieve what you want; you can either instantiate the `SomeScript` and run its contents or you can evaluate `SomeScript` using groovy shell. The script needs to be executed so the variable will be created in the binding:

SomeScript.groovy:

```
bindingC = {
    110.0
}
```

OtherScript.groovy solution 1:

```
s = new GroovyShell().evaluate new File("SomeScript.groovy")
assert s.bindingC() == 110.0
```

OtherScript.groovy solution 2:

```
s2 = new SomeScript() // SomeScript is also an instance of groovy.lang.Script
s2.run()
assert s2.bindingC() == 110.0
```

Comment: the local closure is not accessible right?  Because it is like a method's local variables.

Comment: @xst, there is also the groovy transformation `@Field`, which can change the scope of a script variable: http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html

Comment: so `@Field` is a `private def var` on the ScriptXXX class except that `private def var` is not allowed in a script while `@Field` is.